# Node.js Socket IO: How to continuously save socket data to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I'm building a 3D game in the browser using `THREE.js`. Lots of fun, but I came across the following situation:

An object in my 3D scene is continuously moving around, driven by user input. I need to save the object's position to my database in real-time.

Let's start at the **front-end**. `Angular.js` is watching my object's position using its built-in `$watch` functionality. The object's position can change *multiple times per second*.

On each change, I emit an event to the backend `Node.js` server using `Socket IO`, like so:

```
socket.emit('update', { 
    id: id,
    position: position
});
```

In the **back-end**, the event is caught and immediatly emitted to other members in the same `Socket IO Room`. This way, everyone in this room will have the most real-time update possible.

Now, because the event can happen *multiple times per second*, I don't want to update my `MongoDB` collection on each change, since this would cause a lot of overhead. Instead, I'm looking for a way of *incidentally* saving data to the database.

I've came up with a solution by using Node.js `setInterval` function, which saves data every `1000ms`. For each distinct `id` (which is unique per object) received on the backend, a new key is created on an JavaScript object, thus keeping track of changes on a per-object basis.

The (simplified) code on the backend:

```
let update_queue = new Object();

// ...

// Update Event
socket.on('update', (msg) => {

    // Flag Changes
    if (!update_queue[msg.id]) update_queue[msg.id] = { changes: true };

    // Set Interval Timer
    if (!update_queue[msg.id].timer) {

        update_queue[msg.id].timer = setInterval(() => {

            if (!update_queue[msg.id].changes) {
                clearInterval(update_queue[msg.id].timer);
                return;
            }

            // This saves data to MongoDB
            Object3DCollection.update(msg.id, msg.position)
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log('saved');
                });

            // Unflag Changes
            update_queue[msg.id].changes = false;

        }, 1000);
    }

    // Immediate Broadcast to Socket Room
    socket.broadcast.to('some_room').emit('object_updated', msg);
});
```

**The Question**

Is this a proper way of handling very frequent socket data and still saving it to a database? Or are there any other suggestions/solutions that are more robuust or work better.

**Note**

*I do not want to wait for my object to be saved to the database and **then** emit the saved data to the rest of the socket room. The delay of database write operations is not suitable for the real-time game situation I'm dealing with.*

Thanks in advance! All suggestions/solutions are appreciated and will be considered.

Comment: sounds reasonable to me. you can lose buffered transactions if your server crashes, but that aside it's fine.

Comment: great, good to hear. I will invest some time in handling an optional crash to be as safe as possible. thanks for the response.